# My JSP page is not fatching data from database. What should I do to Improve this?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a Spring application, in which CRUD operation is being performed. I am unable to fetch data from database using JSP `${tempClients.firstName}` code. The browser keeps printing the same code as I have written in the JSP file. I have connectivity with Database. Which are of code should I consider to check? The console is not throwing any errors.

```
<c:forEach var="tempClients" items="${clientsModel}">
   <tr>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.firstName}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.lastName}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.email}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.mobileNumber}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.city}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.country}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.domain}</td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clients")
public class Clients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="mobilenumber")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name="domain")
    private String domain;

    @Column(name="requirments")
    private String requirments;

    @Column(name="startdate")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name="enddate")
    private Date endDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Output in Web-Browser

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa1Vf.png):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your JSP page prints the ${tempClients.firstName}?

which may mean your JSP page is ignoring the el expression.

> try this `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`
>
> You can also add the following to your web.xml to enable it for all pages:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-enabled>true</el-enabled>
    <scripting-enabled>true</scripting-enabled>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```